# SQL - Create two new row entries depending on specific column values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a databasetable which contains some address data. My Problem is some rows have two housenumber entries, which look like this:

```
'8, 8A'
'12,14'
```

What I want to do, is:

- To split this rows into two seperate rows
- The new rows have each the specific housenumber
- Deleting the old row with the two entries
- The new rows should have the same values for the other columns than before

The housenumber column is a textfield, because there can be additions like 'A', 'B', etc.
I'd like to know if there is any way to do this in sql, so any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here is what my table looks like:
[image]

Comment: I suppose your table has more than that column? Add one more column to the sample data, and also specify the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this

**Data**

```
CREATE TABLE address
(house_number VARCHAR(20),
 street   VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO address  VALUES ('8, 8A', 'High Street');
INSERT INTO address VALUES ('12, 14', 'New Street');
INSERT INTO address VALUES ('1', 'First Street');
```

**Solution**

```
SELECT TRIM(adr_split.house_number) AS house_number, adr.street
  FROM address adr, UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(adr.house_number, ',')) adr_split(house_number);
```

**Output**

```
house_number    street
8               High Street
8A              High Street
12              New Street
14              New Street
1               First Street
```

In terms of replacing this output with your old data, you can do this

```
CREATE TABLE new_address
(house_number VARCHAR(20),
 street   VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO new_address
SELECT TRIM(adr_split.house_number) AS house_number, adr.street
  FROM address adr, UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(adr.house_number, ',')) adr_split(house_number);

DROP TABLE address;

ALTER TABLE new_address RENAME TO address;
```

Now the address table would have the data as you expected.

Output

```
SELECT * FROM address;

    house_number    street
    8   High Street
    8A  High Street
    12  New Street
    14  New Street
    1   First Street
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select left(col_1, charindex(',', col_1))
  from table_1
 where charindex(',', col_1) > 0
 union 
select substring(col_1, charindex(',', col_1), 255)
  from table_1
 where charindex(',', col_1) > 0
 union 
select col_1
  from table_1
 where charindex(',', col_1) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

without knowledge on all columns its hard to say, but basically idea would be:

prepare:

```
t=# with a(i,addr) as (values(1,$$'8, 8A'
'12,14'$$))
select * into so4 from a;
SELECT 1
```

check:

```
t=# select * from so4;
 i |  addr
---+---------
 1 | '8, 8A'+
   | '12,14'
(1 row)
```

action:

```
t=# with a as (select i, unnest(string_to_array(addr,chr(10))) from so4 group by i, addr)
, i as (insert into so4 select * from a)
delete from so4 using a where a.i = so4.i and a.unnest <> so4.addr
;
DELETE 1
```

check:

```
t=# select * from so4;
 i |  addr
---+---------
 1 | '8, 8A'
 1 | '12,14'
(2 rows)
```